# Json doesn't work with specified URL

Tags: java, android, json, server, hosting

I am a new programmer i am trying to build an app with Json.
If i use this URL doesn't work .  http://zsuzsafodraszat.hostzi.com/boltok.json
if i Use this, my app working.  https://api.myjson.com/bins/3zm8i
Both Json files exactly the same. 
Can you help me what i am doing wrong ? Maybe bad extension or web000 is not a good service for Json ? Can you give me some good free json hosting ? Thanks

Comment: They both work when i try it (both valid json on jsonlint.com)

Comment: @Knetig jsons are not the same. **?d=1279,** vs **?id=1279",**

Comment: The problem appears to be your "app," not the JSON files. Tell us more about your app and the error you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those 2 urls do not have the same content or the same headers. You can see this if run curl commands from the command line:

```
$ curl -i "http://zsuzsafodraszat.hostzi.com/boltok.json"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 13 Apr 2016 22:52:50 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Wed, 13 Apr 2016 16:48:23 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1020
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json

??{"Aldi":"http://catalog.aldi.com/emag/hu_HU/print/Online_katalogus_04_07/Online_katalogus_04_07.pdf",
"Lidl":"http://www.lidl.hu/statics/lidl-hu/ds_doc/HU_HHZ_kw14_2016.pdf",
"Spar":"http://ajanlatok.spar.hu/view/download/?d=1279",
"Penny":"https://view.publitas.com/16538/136265/pdfs/016f82fb5b00bc97b5a8c35f512d89b01cd3e3ce.pdf",
"Coop":"https://view.publitas.com/2556/133497/pdfs/16603d7e9bf30e8a8a4efec7f01d3fa2caf92fe0.pdf",
"Auchan":"http://www.lidl.hu/statics/lidl-hu/ds_doc/HU_HHZ_kw14_2016.pdf"}

$ curl -i "https://api.myjson.com/bins/3zm8i"            
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.5.8
Date: Wed, 13 Apr 2016 22:52:56 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 500
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

{"Aldi":"http://catalog.aldi.com/emag/hu_HU/print/Online_katalogus_04_07/Online_katalogus_04_07.pdf","Lidl":"http://www.lidl.hu/statics/lidl-hu/ds_doc/HU_HHZ_kw14_2016.pdf","Spar":"http://ajanlatok.spar.hu/view/download/?id=1279","Penny":"https://view.publitas.com/16538/136265/pdfs/016f82fb5b00bc97b5a8c35f512d89b01cd3e3ce.pdf","Coop":"https://view.publitas.com/2556/133497/pdfs/16603d7e9bf30e8a8a4efec7f01d3fa2caf92fe0.pdf","Auchan":"http://www.lidl.hu/statics/lidl-hu/ds_doc/HU_HHZ_kw14_2016.pdf"}
```

As you can see, one of them has a couple of junk bytes at the beginning that my terminal is displaying as question marks. Also the http headers are different. The Content-Lengths are wildly different too. Did you use something other than a plain text editor to create the json payload in the failing example?

Try removing the junk characters and adding these http headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```